# Opening a File from a FileInfo

Tags: go

In golang, if I have an `os.FileInfo`, is there any way to open an `*os.File` from that by itself without the original path?

Let's say I had something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

var files []os.FileInfo

func walker(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if strings.HasSuffix(info.Name(), ".txt") {
        files = append(files, info)
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    err := filepath.Walk("/tmp/foo", walker)
    if err != nil {
        println("Error", err)
    } else {
        for _, f := range files {
            println(f.Name())
            // This is where we'd like to open the file
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to convert `FileInfo` to `* File`? The code I'm actually working with isn't based on `filepath.Walk`; but I do get an `[]os.FileInfo` slice back. I still have the root directory, and the file name, but it seems like any further sub-tree information has gone by this stage.

Comment: Have you tried storing the path from your `walker` func? That would give you the complete path including the subdirectory and file name. Maybe use a map[string]os.FileInfo to store the path as the key then use that to open the file.

Comment: I'm aware that that would give me the full path, and I'd be fine. As I said in the question though, I'm not actually using filepath.Walk, so don't have the path string at the time.

Comment: The code I actually have uses ioutil.ReadDir and is a lot more ugly than the example here. While I know there is a solution to the higher level problem I have (i.e. walking a directory tree, and storing the paths), my specific question is if I need to do all that refactoring, or if there is a simple way to go from os.FileInfo to an os.File?

Comment: I'm fairly confident the answer is no but I'm looking around a little to confirm that.

Comment: Besides there could be multiple paths and the user could only have access to some of them: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32300#issuecomment-496984069

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No. The `FileInfo` interface simply does not expose the path and all provided methods in the `os` and `ioutil` packages accept the pathname as a string.

Answer (score 11):

As additional info, this is how to constructor the filename string including path:

```
filename := filepath.Join(path, info.Name())
```

Answer (score 4):

No, a file cannot be opened with just the FileInfo. os.Open only takes a string. You should always have the path or the parent path because that is the only way to get a FileInfo.